# How do I evaluate model performance using Bayes Theorem?

Tags: model-evaluation, bayes-rule

Assume that I have a model $f$ whose task is to do entity resolution. Given a name, say *Samsung!!*, it would (hopefully) return *Samsung* along with a confidence score in $[0, 1]$.

Now, assume that it has generated 100 results stored in a vector $\vec{x}$ = [("Samsung", 0.94), .., (name_100, score_100)] which has been manually verified to be either correct or incorrect, in another vector $\vec{v}$ = [("Samsung", True), .., (name_100, boolean_100)].

How could one use Bayes Rule to compute the probability of $P(\text{is true}| \text{model score})$, given a previous records of model scores + manual verification?